# "In graduate programs" versus "at graduate level"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am writing a new CV. I want to choose a title for a section which specifies the courses I've taken at the graduate level. Since I've attended more than one graduate programs, which one of these is preferred for the title?

1. Courses taken at graduate level
2. Courses taken in graduate program

Comment: Why not "graduate level courses"?

Comment: Somebody told me the other one is better. I think this one is better :) Neither of us has any good reason for it. I just wonder if my feeling is true or not.

Comment: I'd prefer "courses taken at _the_ graduate level", myself.  I can't think another way to rephrase the second sentence nicely that keeps "program" in there.

Comment: Does it make sense if I delete the _"the"_ from the title?

Comment: No, that sounds fairly wrong to my ear.  For example, Wikipedia's article on "graduate school" says the following: "admission...is usually restricted...to those who may benefit professionally from additional study _the graduate level_" i.e. it constructs the phrase in the same manner I have. Every time I've heard "graduate level", it's always required the article _the_ with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **Courses taken at graduate level** is more appropriate since it will imply that you are referring to all the courses you have pursued while in graduate program(s).

On the other hand, **Courses taken in graduate program** would limit the clarity and one may end up assuming that you did only one graduate program.

On you can say **Courses pursued in graduate programs**, but the first one seems more appropriate to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, "**courses taken at graduate level**" just about sounds perfect.
It also removes the need to pinpoint any specific program that was taken.

"courses taken at graduate program", on the other hand should ideally be followed by the name of the program. This should be used only in the event that you have taken multiple programs at graduate level and is redundant otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could just sum it up as

> Post-graduate courses

or

> Post-graduate course work

or

> Post-graduate studies

Comment: You should not say "course work" because in some usage this refers to coursework (like assessed essays) as opposed to examinations.  So "course work" sounds like it describes some essays you wrote rather than some courses you did.